# iOS: Orientation get future self.view.bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, rotation, orientation, bounds

**Background:** I wanted to animate the change in my content along with the orientation. My content position is relative to the `self.view.bounds`.

**Problem:** In order to animate the content along with the bounds, I would need to know what would the bounds of the view be at the end. I can hard code it but I hope to find a more dynamic way.

**Codes:** So all animation takes place in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` as per following:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    //centering the image
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x + (self.view.bounds.size.width - image.size.width)/2 , self.view.bounds.origin.y + (self.view.bounds.size.height - image.size.height)/2, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%d",[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.bounds.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.bounds.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.bounds.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.bounds.size.height);

}
```

The bounds are *before* the orientation change. Thus, this only works if the transformation is 180 degrees. If I were to use `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`, the animation will be *after* the orientation change which looks awful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` instead. This method gets called from within the rotation animation block, and all the bounds have been set correctly at this point. [Docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Did not know exist :) Thank you.

Comment: Ahh... been looking for this for a long time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it dynamic then when you initialize imageView, set the `autoresizingMask` property so that when the imageView's superview resizes on the rotate the margins can auto resize themselves...

```
 imageView = //init imageView
 imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
 //addtional config
```

This means you only need to set the frame once then the imageView will always adjust itself to stay in the middle.

Check out the UIView class reference http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html to see what else you can do with the autoresizingMask property

Comment: +1 for great idea. I will have to go for the answer above though, since it is actually what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, **you just need to swap the X/Y coordinates and width/height in you're CGRectMake**, to get your future layout for a 90 degree change. If it's 180 degree change, then it's the same as current

```
CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.y + (self.view.bounds.size.height - image.size.height)/2 , self.view.bounds.origin.x + (self.view.bounds.size.width - image.size.width)/2, image.size.height, image.size.width);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is however, quite a hack. Because then you would have to handle 180 degrees flip, etc. Not really worth it. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Definitely a hack, but hacks have there place to. 3 second hack > than an hour on google if your on a deadline